# DIFFERENCE between GIT merge and GIT push origin

Tags: git, branch, git-workflow

I'm working on a team where we have a branch called development.From the branch I created another local branch on my own computer.When I'm on the local branch, what is the difference between running the commands 'git merge development' and 'git push origin development' from my local branch?

New to git and every team has their own theory on the best workflow.

Answer (score 5):

```
git merge development
```

merges the changes from development into your local branch

```
git push origin development
```

pushes your development branch to the remote origin

But it sounds like you need a bit of help in general with git, please read this: http://git-scm.com/book